# How to bind and display multi line chart to form?

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultracart

I am using VB2017 and have data returned from Stored Procedure and I have filled a DataTable with data. The data in Datatable sample is

Date                      Bill                   Fred                  Jack
Date1                     25                     115                   33

Date2                     88                     15                    24

Date3                     41                     31                   162

I have set UltraChart datasource to the datatable and then Bind data

```
     Dim datTab As New DataTable
            Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(datTab)
            End Using
            ugResolved.Data.SwapRowsAndColumns = True
            ugResolved.Data.DataSource = datTab
            ugResolved.Data.DataBind()
```

When I run The chart isn't displayed. Get Box with the following text in it. Data Not Available. Please call Ultrachart.Data.DataBind() after setting valid Data.DataSource.

I have set the dataSource. What I am missing. Just starting using these controls. I have gotten the UltraGrid and UltraChart StackColumnChart working. Can anyone advise what I am missing.
I posted to Infragistics forums but still waiting couple of days later.

I would like a line for each name with line going from day to using the numbers as their path for each date

Comment: And when you debug, the ````dataTab```` DataTable has rows?

Comment: yes.  debugging DataTable rows each field in row has a value. The stored procedure is passed a number for how many days user want to report on. So if I pass 8 days I get the last days days results. the column names would be col0 is word Date and each column after that would have a user ie col1 is 'Bill'. The stored procedure is returning 8 rows in that example.

Comment: Okay, sorry I can't help more.  I thought maybe the SqlAdapter wasn't actually adding the data you thought it was.  But typically, you set the DataSource and then DataBind() it.

Comment: Is this ASP.Net where ````ugResolved```` is the ID of your custom control?

Comment: Yes ugResolved in name of my control. This is not asp.Net. Straight VB using visual studio 2017 with Infragstics UltraChart control

Comment: Well, hopefully someone else has experience with this UltraChart or you get a response on their forum.